# What is a good extendable blogging application for ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, blogs

I am looking for a relatively good and well supported, and preferably open source blog application that runs on [ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET) and [SQL Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server). It doesn’t need to be packed full of features, it just needs the basics, such as tagging, comments, etc. Extra features are a bonus.

I would also like it to be either open source or have an extendable framework for customization of not only the look, but the functionality; preferably written in C# if it's open source, as that is my language of choice.

Good performance, etc., the usual stuff when looking for applications.

Even if it's a [CMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system) with a blog in it, that would be beneficial to point out as well.

Please give the name, a link, and some of the the things you find good about it. Even if someone has posted what you were going to post, but you have other things you like about it, please add those things anyway.

---

I have garnered from the responses to check out [BlogEngine.Net](http://www.dotnetblogengine.net/), [subtext](http://subtextproject.com/), [dasBlog](http://www.dasblog.info/), and to stay away from the blog in [DotNetNuke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DotNetNuke). I will start with BlogEngine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used [BlogEngine.NET](http://www.dotnetblogengine.net/) for one of [my clients](http://blog.atomium.be/), can definitely recommend it.

Comment: thx, i probably should have posted it is for one of my clients as well, but if its good i may end up using it myself as a working blog to keep my cleints updated.

Comment: It has some nice skins and plenty of 3rd party add-ons as well, its very good.

Comment: Looks like it will be BlogEngine for me.

Answer (score 3):

The two big ones are [BlogRngine.NET](http://www.dotnetblogengine.net/) and [Subtext](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtext_%28software%29). [dasblog](https://dasblog.codeplex.com/) is good, but just be aware that it's run on XML; there's no database backend which is both a pro and con.

I would strongly recommend you stay well away from the [DotNetNuke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DotNetNuke) blogging engine. It's low on features, difficult to configure and not very intuitive to use.

Answer (score 2):

*[Subtext](http://subtextproject.com/)* is a good option. I haven't seen it provide tag clouds, but other than that it works very well!

To quote from their site:

> Subtext is an open source project
>   licensed under the BSD license. It is
>   a fork of the popular .TEXT blogging
>   platform.

It run as an ASP.NET/C# site and connects to SQL Server.

Comment: I have just been told that it supports tags, you just need to choose a skin that provides that functionality.

Comment: Also note it was the brainchild of Phil Haack, a member of StackOverflow and the current head honcho for the MVC framework. They are also looking at rewriting SubText using the MVC framework

Comment: Interesting note. I will kep that in mind. Would make it quite interesting under MVC. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

There are two I know of: BlogEngine.NET and DasBlog

I'm using BlogEngine.NET. It is very easy to extend as it uses the providers for membership and such. It can be configured to run on SQL Server, but by default it will run using XML.

DasBlog should also be a great blog engine, although I have never really played with it.

Both are open source and are in C#.